# java how to write 0x13 unicode character?

Tags: java, unicode

how to print 0x13 Unicode character in java ???

Comment: @g.revolution - it might be a worthwhile thing to take some time to review your old questions and accept some answers, where appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Unicode escape:

```
System.out.print("\u0013");
```

Remember that Unicode escapes are replaced by the compiler by the corresponding Unicode character which *can* introduce compiler errors.

Comment: Though `\r` is not 0x13 but 0x0d.

Comment: Argh, sorry. Ok, that simplifies the answer a bit :-)